# What are "." and ".." in a directory?

Tags: windows

Based on the question: [How to make using command prompt less painful](https://superuser.com/questions/33366/how-to-make-using-command-prompt-less-painful), what are the `.` and `..` entries in the most voted answer? I see it when I do a `dir` command but it isn't visible to the user in the form of a file.

In case you dont know what I mean here's an example:

```
.
..
Su.exe
Sup.txt
SuperUser.COM
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The . is the current directory, while .. signifies the parent directory. It makes things quicker at the command line as well so you don't need to type out full paths.

example:

go up 2 directories:

```
cd ..\..\
```

or on a UNIX based system, to run executable binaries in the current directory:

```
./program
```

A lot of UNIX scripts will also utilize . to represent the current directory, in order to scan for files for example (Perl):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

opendir ( DIR, "." ) || die "Error opening current directory\n";
while( ($f = readdir(DIR))){
     print("$f\n");
}
closedir(DIR);
```

It is much more portable if you wish to move the script around to different directories or systems since a directory name is not hard-coded.

Comment: It's little known, but the Windows command line extends this further.

. = this directory
.. = parent directory
... = parent's parent directory

3 dots is sometimes useful, much more than that and it's just too hard to deal with.

Comment: 3 dots does not work for me, using Vista

Comment: nor me on Windows 7 64 bit RTM. Sounds like a myth to me. what's wrong with ..\.. anyway?

Comment: @salmonmoose: Doesn't work for me on XP either.

Comment: Does not work for me on NT 3.51 either

Comment: "..." is not valid.  just "." and ".."

Comment: `cd ...` [works for me on Windows 98's `command`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/fdmZX.png). [Windows XP doesn't seem to support it though](http://i.stack.imgur.com/AQr8y.png).

Comment: Nice answer . Works for me.

Answer (score 10):

The `..` is used to navigate up the hierarchy of the file system. It's useful when you don't want to type a long path, or when writing a script/program that doesn't know where exactly it will be installed but it knows that `../media/` should hold all the images/videos/icons etc.

The single dot `.` is useful in linux where you want to run an executable in the current directory so you type `./a.out` because the command shell by default doesn't search the current directory for executable files (for security reasons).

The single dot `.` is also used if you want to pass the current directory as an argument to a command.

Comment: PowerShell also doesn't include . in the path list for searching executables.

Comment: How to pass '.' as an argument to a command?

Comment: @DeFu you pass the dot as a dot, for example: `ls .`

Comment: `ls  ` functions same as `ls .`

Comment: @DeFu well yes but when you do `ls .` you _are_ passing '.' as an argument to 'ls'; isn't that what you asked? It functions the same because by default `ls` lists the current directory, and `.` is the current directory. But you _are_ passing it to the command, for sure.

Answer (score 5):

The . is the current directory. You rarely need to use this; most commands will assume the current directory. The .. is the next level up; this is a rather useful shortcut. If you are in C:\foo\bar and you want to go to C:\foo\bar2 you can say

```
cd ..\bar2
```

and you will be in C:\foo\bar2. If you don't want to go to bar2 but only want to run C:\foo\bar.exe, then you can say

```
..\bar.exe
```

or
    ..\bar
to run it without going back up to the parent directory. Of course, this is more useful when you are it represents a longer path that C:\foo (such as "C:\Users\Daniel\My Dropbox\".

Comment: I find . to be quite useful at times, especially when copying or moving files to the current location (`copy F:\*.foo .`) or referring to it otherwise (`start .` opens the Explorer in the current directory, for example).

Answer (score 3):

They stand for:

```
.
```

The current dir

```
..
```

Represents the parent dir

So if you have the executable "su.exe" in:

- Your Path environment variable ( let say C:\MyExecutables\su.exe )
- Your current dir
- Your parent dir.

You could execute each one like this:

```
 su.exe
```

Executes the one in the Path

```
.\su.exe
```

Executes the one in the current dir

```
..\su.exe
```

Executes the one in the parent dir.