# Is there a specific name for the .. or . on *nix systems?

Tags: unix, shell, terminology

Just what it says. Do they have a name besides "those dot thingies"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're called directory abbreviations.

**.** = current directory
**..** = parent directory

See [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/37449/what-is-and-in-a-directory/37451#37451) for a bit more information. Section 2.13 (CTRL-F for 2.13) on [this page](http://sunsite.utk.edu/UNIX-help/quickref.html) also covers them.

Comment: They're instead of Their

Answer (score 2):

They're normally called 'dot' and 'dot-dot' in my experience.  I don't know that they have a collective name - they're just the entries that hold the hierarchical file system together, and they aren't shown by '`ls(1)`' by default because they're always there (and other names beginning with dot are also not shown).

As John T says, they're meanings are fixed - dot is a name for the current directory, and dot-dot is a name for the parent directory.

If you look at a Unix 7th Edition manual, you'd find that there wasn't a `mkdir(2)` system call, but the super-user could use the `link(2)` system call to make the dot and dot-dot entries in a directory (and `mknod(2)` to make the directory), and the `mkdir(1)` program was, consequently, a setuid root program that did the job properly.  If misused, you could end up with an incorrectly hierarchical file system - and one of the jobs of the `fsck(8)` program was to check for, and if necessary fix, mis-assembled directory hierarchies.