# Pass `.` the current directory symbol as an argument

Tags: linux, filesystems

I read [Windows - What are "." and ".." in a directory? - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/37449/what-are-and-in-a-directory)

It explains:

> The single dot `.` is also used if you want to pass the current directory as an argument to a command.

I am very confused. Can somebody give an example?

Comment: There are examples in the comments under that particular answer. What exactly don't you understand or are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is about Windows but you tagged [linux](/questions/tagged/linux) so my answer applies to Linux.

Every time you invoke a command, there's some *working directory* your're in at the moment; `.` denotes this directory. `pwd` is a general command to know what this directory is. While working in a shell like `bash` you can "go" to another directory with `cd /another/directory/path`.

Some commands (like `cd` above) accept directories (i.e. their paths) as argument(s). Now I'm feeling like talking about obvious basics; but your question seems to be basic, so here we go. The general syntax to pass an argument to `some_command` is like:

```
some_command argument
```

or even arbitrary number of arguments (four in this example):

```
some_command argument1 argument2 "argument3 with spaces" argument4
```

You can use `.` as an argument instead of the path returned by `pwd`. *If* the command interprets it as a path to directory then it should be understood as the current working directory. Although `cd .` has little sense because it makes your shell "go" to the same directory it's already in, the syntax is perfectly valid. Useful example is

```
df .
```

It reports disk space usage of the filesystem where your current working directory resides.

There are commands that operate on current working directory by default: `ls` is equivalent to `ls .`, `du` is equivalent to `du .`. Note this is not always the case: `df` prints all available filesystems while `df .` prints just one of them.

---

I wrote "*if* the command interprets it as a path to directory" because some commands don't. E.g. in `bash` the command

```
tr . , <<< foo.bar
```

will print `foo,bar` (`tr` replaces `.` with `,` in the given `foo.bar` string). This is because `tr` interprets `.` as a single-character string.

This shows `.` is not translated to current directory path by the shell. Compare this to `~` which is translated to the value of `$HOME` (try `echo ~` in `bash`). The interpretation of `.` as a certain path lays way deep inside the design of directory tree in Linux (broader: in UNIX).

So every command can interpret `.` on its own. But when it's meant to be a directory path, the convention is it should be the current working directory. Linux understands this and provides tools to support this "conversion".

---

Also note `ls -a` almost always prints `.` among the "real" directory content. It gets interesting when your current working directory gets deleted. In this case `ls -a` prints nothing, but `ls .` or `df .` still work, as if `.` was there.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly contrived Windows example:
you can use **`.`** to set the attributes of the current directory:

```
C:\Path\to\Some\Directory> md sub1 sub2

C:\Path\to\Some\Directory> attrib * /s /d
             C:\Path\to\Some\Directory\sub1
             C:\Path\to\Some\Directory\sub2

C:\Path\to\Some\Directory> cd sub2

C:\Path\to\Some\Directory\sub2> attrib +r .

C:\Path\to\Some\Directory\sub2> cd ..

C:\Path\to\Some\Directory> attrib * /s /d
             C:\Path\to\Some\Directory\sub1
     R       C:\Path\to\Some\Directory\sub2
```

Here we set the read-only attribute on the `sub2` directory
while we’re in it. 
`attrib +r .` is shorter and easier to type
than `attrib +r ..\sub2` or `attrib +r C:\Path\to\Some\Directory \sub2`.