# conhost.exe shows multiple times

Tags: windows-7

I have windows 7 and task mgr shows about 20 conhost.exe's running???????

Answer (score 1):

[It runs the console windows in explorer.](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/4996/what-is-conhost.exe-and-why-is-it-running/)

Previously answered on SU [here](https://superuser.com/questions/27347/what-is-conhost-exe).