# See contents of conhost

Tags: windows, stdout, stdin, conhost

Every now and then, various programs create conhost.exe processes on my (Windows 7 x64) computer. I know they are console windows, except the windows themselves are hidden.

I don't suspect any malware, but being a curious person, I'd still like to know what they are doing.

Specifically, I'd like some way to view or dump STDIN and STDOUT of [conhost processes that I didn't create myself]. Does anyone know how to do that?

Edit: This got marked as a duplicate of another question. Perhaps I was unclear. I know exactly what conhost.exe is. What I'm asking for is different.

I know how to capture stdin, stdout and stderr of child processes. However, here I'd like to capture those streams of processes I did not create myself. Given the lack of information I can find, I'm beginning to suspect it is impossible, but perhaps someone knows some arcane magic that would be of use.

Comment: Questions on SU are expected to [show some research effort](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) on your part and should be included in your question please.

Comment: Related: [What is the 'conhost.exe' process that shows up in Task Manager](http://superuser.com/q/27347/376602)