# How to scroll up in windows CMD window?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, scrolling

As you know directional key and page keys are used to move between command history items. How can I scroll up using the keyboard?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[cmd.exe is a *shell* and not a *terminal*](https://superuser.com/q/144666/241386). Many terminals actually have their own way to scroll the console window without passing the shortcut key to the shell so you can easily scroll any shells running in it including cmd

The default terminal in older Windows is [conhost.exe](https://superuser.com/q/27347/241386) and it's scrolling feature can be accessed via <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>L</kbd> then <kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd> or <kbd>PageUp</kbd>/<kbd>PageDown</kbd> as Remirol answered (update: now deleted), and it works in PowerShell too because PowerShell also uses conhost by default. But PowerShell already has its own more convenient scrolling shortcut which is <kbd>PageUp</kbd>/<kbd>PageDown</kbd>. Other shells may have similar keys, like <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PageUp</kbd>/<kbd>PageDown</kbd> in bash. Unfortunately cmd only has a key to scroll by line and not by page

If you use another better terminal then they likely have their own scrolling shortcut. For example

- In [Windows terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal) ([default in Windows 11](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-terminal-is-now-the-default-in-windows-11/) and can be installed to older Windows) shortcut keys can be [defined by yourself](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/customize-settings/startup) in `settings.json`. Here's an example that you can add to the `"keybindings"` array in that file

  ```js
    // Unbind keys first from any other actions so that we can use
    { "command": "unbound", "keys": "ctrl+shift+pageup" },
    { "command": "unbound", "keys": "ctrl+shift+pagedown" },
    { "command": "unbound", "keys": "ctrl+shift+up" },
    { "command": "unbound", "keys": "ctrl+shift+down" },

    { "command": "scrollUpPage", "keys": "ctrl+shift+pageup" },
    { "command": "scrollDownPage", "keys": "ctrl+shift+pagedown" },
    { "command": "scrollUp", "keys": "ctrl+shift+up" },
    { "command": "scrollDown", "keys": "ctrl+shift+down" },
  ```
- In [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/en/) (and its "extension" [cmder](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder)) there are various [`Key.Buf*Up` and `Key.Buf*Dn` events](https://conemu.github.io/en/KeyboardShortcuts.html) to scroll the buffer. By default <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Up/Down</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp/PgDn</kbd> will be used to scroll a line and a page respectively

Comment: I found myself here searching for the equivalent Windows Terminal keybindings and through trial and error it turns out `ctrl + shift + Page Up / Up Arrow Key` works by default without entries in the settings.json.